# Want to display a sliding and collapsible menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, collapsable

[menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU3PU.jpg)

i wanted to add a menu which is collapsible and expanding by using hamburger translation but i am not able to do this. can anybody help me to obtain this menu.

```js
$(".menu-opener").click(function(){
  $(".menu-opener, .menu-opener-inner, .menu").toggleClass("active");

});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.menu a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-opener, .menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active, .menu-opener-inner, .menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after, .menu, .menu.active {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms all;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

.menu-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 0%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 64px;
}
.menu-opener:hover, .menu-opener.active {
  background: #f1c40f;
}

.menu-opener-inner {
  background: #fff;
  height: .5rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}
.menu-opener-inner::before, .menu-opener-inner::after {
  background: white;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: .5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}
.menu-opener-inner::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  transform: translateY(0.25rem);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active {
  background: transparent;
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu-opener-inner.active::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu {
  background: #ededee;
  color: #000;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 0rem;
  z-index: -1  ;
}
.menu.active {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
}
.menu.active .menu-link {
  color: white;
}

.menu-inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link {
  color: transparent;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-link li {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="menu-opener">
           <div class="menu-opener-inner"></div>
         </nav>
         <nav class="menu">
           <ul class="menu-inner">
             <a href="#" class="menu-link">
               <li>HOME</li>
             </a>
             <a href="location.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>LOCATION</li>
             </a>
             <a href="stay.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>STAY</li>
             </a>
             <a href="eat.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>EAT &amp; DRINK</li>
             </a>
             <a href="relax.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>RELAX &amp; UNWIND</li>
             </a>
             <a href="events.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>EVENTS</li>
             </a>
             <a href="gallery.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>GALLERY</li>
             </a>
             <a href="contact.html" class="menu-link">
               <li>CONTACT US</li>
             </a>
             <a href="#" class="menu-link">
               <li><img src="images\common\logo.png" class="menu-link" alt="" height="25px" width="120px"></a></li>
             </a>
           </ul>
         </nav>
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: First of all, Please add JQuery as that is missing.

Comment: I added that jquery already. its in first code snippet.

Comment: Did you try executing your above code? You need to include JQuery. Just click on 'Run code snippet'

Comment: no i have not.. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Added the `JQuery`, formatted the code, and its working perfectly fine:

```js
$(".menu-opener").click(function() {
  $(".menu-opener, .menu-opener-inner, .menu").toggleClass("active");

});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-opener,
.menu-opener:hover,
.menu-opener.active,
.menu-opener-inner,
.menu-opener-inner::before,
.menu-opener-inner::after,
.menu,
.menu.active {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms all;
  transition: 250ms all;
}

.menu-opener {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 0%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 64px;
}

.menu-opener:hover,
.menu-opener.active {
  background: #f1c40f;
}

.menu-opener-inner {
  background: #fff;
  height: .5rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
  margin-top: 1.75rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.menu-opener-inner::before,
.menu-opener-inner::after {
  background: white;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: .5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.menu-opener-inner::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
  transform: translateY(-0.75rem);
}

.menu-opener-inner::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25rem);
  transform: translateY(0.25rem);
}

.menu-opener-inner.active {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-opener-inner.active::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(0rem) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-opener-inner.active::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu {
  background: #ededee;
  color: #000;
  height: 64px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 1%;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 0rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu.active {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
}

.menu.active .menu-link {
  color: white;
}

.menu-inner {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 4rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-link {
  color: transparent;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-link li {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu-opener">
  <div class="menu-opener-inner"></div>
</nav>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-inner">
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      <li>HOME</li>
    </a>
    <a href="location.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>LOCATION</li>
    </a>
    <a href="stay.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>STAY</li>
    </a>
    <a href="eat.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>EAT &amp; DRINK</li>
    </a>
    <a href="relax.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>RELAX &amp; UNWIND</li>
    </a>
    <a href="events.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>EVENTS</li>
    </a>
    <a href="gallery.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>GALLERY</li>
    </a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="menu-link">
      <li>CONTACT US</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">
      <li><img src="images\common\logo.png" class="menu-link" alt="" height="25px" width="120px"></a>
    </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```